# Python + Flask, post button using name

Tags: python, flask

I got three buttons like:

```
<form method="post"> 
<input type="submit" name="one" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete"> 
<input type="submit" name="two" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete"> 
<input type="submit" name="three" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete"> 
</form>
```

Is there way to post button with out using name="submit"

I am using post like

```
 if request.method == "POST":
  if request.form['submit'] == 'Delete':
```

But it works only for

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">
```

I tried:

```
if request.form['one'] == 'Delete':
```

But nothing happens.

Comment: you mean without using type=submit ?

Comment: if request.form['submit'] == 'Delete': (for name="submit) it works, but i want to create post for "name="one"

Comment: type=submit  must stay it is button submit

Comment: are they within the same form or different form? please post the form code

Comment: <form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="one" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">

<input type="submit" name="two" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">

<input type="submit" name="three" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">
</form>

Comment: please update the question to make it more readable, also write your POST method handler in python

Comment: Any ideas ? How to post 3 buttons in one form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forms are used to receive input from a user and process it with a backend script. However, it appears that you are not taking in user input and instead, using the submit tags and buttons. Instead of a form to trigger an action, just use three `href`s or three buttons with an onlick action:

Option 1: Three `href`s to redirect to a specific route for the operation:

```
<a href='/my_action1' class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
<a href='/my_action2' class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
<a href='/my_action3' class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
```

Now, in your main flask app file, create the routes to handle the operation:

```
@app.route('/my_action1')
def do_something1():
  return
@app.route('/my_action2')
def do_something2():
  return
@app.route('/my_action3')
def do_something3():
  return
```

Option 2:Three buttons with an `onclick`:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick='do_something()'>Delete</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick='do_something1()'>Delete</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick='do_something2()'>Delete</button>
```

In `<script>`:

```
function do_something(){
  //perform specific operation
  alert('something');
}
function do_something1(){
  //perform specific operation
  alert('something1');
}
function do_something2(){
  //perform specific operation
  alert('something2');
}
```